# Join on 1=1 versus cross join

Tags: sql, join

I am joining a large table in postgresql to a table with 1 row in it. Yes, I know I could just take the values from this single row table and put them in my query written out, but there's 210 columns.

So my question is this: should I join up the single row table to everything using a cross join or using a regular join on a tautology (1 = 1 or something). Is either of those ways bound to be slower?

Or is there a third faster way?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You need to have all 210 columns in the join condition?

Comment: Use `cross join` to make your intention clear. Otherwise next year you (or someone having to change your code) will wonder what that stupid `1=1` was supposed to mean.

Comment: Measure performance insted of asking for solution.

Comment: Why not use 2 queries if it's the same values for the 210 columns on every row?

Comment: As far as I have worked with, cross join is faster

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You should make that an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to select from two tables in SQL Server with no common field to join on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582313/correct-way-to-select-from-two-tables-in-sql-server-with-no-common-field-to-join)

Comment: Worth pointing out...  if you did a join ON table1.Id=table1.Id   when what you really intended to do was a join ON table1.Id=table2.Id   then that is effectively also a join ON  1=1  (so please watch out for that joining mistake when constructing delete queries)

Answer (score 11):

One thing to note is a cross join will result in an empty table if one of the tables is empty.  If one of your tables might be empty and you still want records, you may want an outer join (e.g. left, right, or full) on 1=1.

Comment: ☝️This right here, that's a huge caveat and a big gotycha

Comment: This fact is so surprising that adding a demonstration may be worthwhile.

Answer (score 5):

The reason `1=1` exists is to make it easier to create dynamic sql statements by concatenating strings together (with the usual safeguards like parameterization, of course).

Having a predefined WHERE clause with `1=1` in it allows additional `WHERE` conditions to be added to the SQL without having to check for the existence of a WHERE clause first, and the SQL engine will generally optimize out the `1=1` so there's no performance difference.

In any other context, `1=1` is generally harmless, but not particularly useful.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. the question is: what is the difference between `select * from t1 join t2 on 1=1` vs. `select * from t1 cross join t2`.

Comment: Yes it does.  See  the last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

They should perform and behave the same - the difference is in developer semantics

Here's a sample demo:

```sql
-- Setup
DECLARE @Codeset TABLE (id INT, [name] VARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @Student TABLE (id INT, [name] VARCHAR(50), age INT);

INSERT INTO @Codeset  
VALUES (1, 'HomeRoom');

INSERT INTO @Student  
VALUES (1, 'Jolly', 20), 
       (2, 'Sally', 22);
```

Let's say we want back every row from `@Student` and also to bring back the name value from `@Codeset`:

```
| id | name  | age | name     |
|----|-------|-----|----------|
| 1  | Jolly | 20  | HomeRoom |
| 2  | Sally | 22  | HomeRoom |
```

Any of the following syntaxes will accomplish this when either table has 0, 1, or 1+ records:

```sql
-- INNER JOIN 1=1
SELECT s.id, s.[name], s.age, c.[name]
FROM @Student s
INNER JOIN @Codeset c ON 1=1

-- Multiple From tables
SELECT s.id, s.[name], s.age, c.[name]
FROM @Student s,
     @Codeset c

-- CROSS JOIN
SELECT s.id, s.[name], s.age, c.[name]
FROM @Student s
CROSS JOIN @Codeset c
```

In this situation, you should prefer [**`CROSS JOIN`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/joins/cross-join) to be as explicit as possible as to your intentions to build a single select statement from multiple unrelated tables

> **Note**: `CROSS JOIN` will output the same as `INNER JOIN ON 1=1`.  Both produce the Cartesian product of all rows in both rowsets, so if one table is empty, the results will be as well.
>
> If you need to guarantee results when `@Students` has records, but `@Codeset` might be empty, you will need to use `LEFT JOIN ON 1=1`

**See Also**: [Correct way to select from two tables in SQL Server with no common field to join on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17582313/1366033)

Answer (score -2):

Based solely on my experience after writing huge amounts of sql. `inner join on 1=1` is much faster than simply `cross join`.

Comment: Please be more elaborative.