# Is CROSS JOIN all we need?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, cross-join

If we got rid of `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`. `RIGHT JOIN`, and `FULL JOIN` tomorrow, could we completely replace their functionality with `CROSS JOIN` and filters on it? I initially thought that we obviously could, but edge cases such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36270903/10319707) have given me doubts.

Comment: that is a bad idea cross join needs lots memory and time to replace a for example an inner join,, also a LEFT and RIGHT JOIN can't be replaced by a cross join

Comment: Why would you `CROSS JOIN`???

Comment: The old ANSI-89 syntax to achieve this was deprecated in 2008 and removed in 2012; why would we go backwards to 1989 again?

Comment: You probably can with some unions but why do you want to, might as well remove joins and use cursors

Comment: I just see this as a question motivated by finding out whether their understanding of joins is correct. Not an actual proposal to just use cross join everywhere. Though the output of cross joining an empty table mentioned in the question proves already that we couldn't so not sure why this was asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a  b
1  1
2  4
```

JOIN

```
1, 1
```

LEFT JOIN

```
1, 1
2, NULL
```

RIGHT JOIN

```
1, 1
NULL, 4
```

FULL JOIN

```
1, 1
2, NULL
NULL, 4
```

CROSS JOIN

```
1, 1
1, 4
2, 1
2, 4
```

How are you going get LEFT JOIN from CROSS JOIN?

Comment: "How are you going get LEFT JOIN from CROSS JOIN?" - not impossible here. Evaluate the `a  = b` result on all rows of the cross join. That returns `1, 1` - keep track for all distinct rows on the left whether they matched anything, notice that `a = 2` never matched anything so needs to be preserved for the outer join semantics and that we need to output `2, NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not logically "all we need".

An `INNER JOIN` is logically just a `CROSS JOIN` with the join predicate evaluated on all rows.

- For left outer joins for any rows in the left table that did not match anything output these with NULL values for the right table columns.
- For right outer joins for any rows in the right table that did not match anything output these with NULL values for the left table columns.
- Full outer joins combine both of these behaviours.

*Most* of the time if you were presented with a `CROSS JOIN` result between table A and B and it contained a row identifier for both table A and B then it would contain enough information to calculate what the outer joined result should be for a particular join predicate (though the SQL to do this would be inefficient)

For example for

```
DECLARE @A TABLE 
(
A_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
A_N INT
)

DECLARE @B TABLE 
(
B_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
B_N INT
)

INSERT @A
VALUES (1, 101),
       (2, 101),
       (3, 102),
       (4, 102);

INSERT @B
VALUES (1, 101),
       (2, 101);
```

Then one way of simulating

```
SELECT *
FROM @A A
LEFT JOIN @B B ON A.A_N = B.B_N;
```

would be ([DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Znvj5T_I))

```
WITH A_cross_join_B AS
(
SELECT *
FROM @A A
CROSS JOIN @B B 
), A_cross_join_B_with_loj_flag AS
(
SELECT *, 
        /*2 if Join predicate matches, 1 if we are preserving a single instance of this row for outer join purposes, 0 otherwise*/
        Flag = CASE WHEN A_N = B_N THEN 2 ELSE CASE WHEN 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A_ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN A_N = B_N THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END
FROM A_cross_join_B
)
SELECT A_ID, 
       A_N, 
       B_ID = CASE WHEN Flag = 2 THEN B_ID END, 
       B_N = CASE WHEN Flag = 2 THEN B_N END
FROM A_cross_join_B_with_loj_flag
WHERE Flag <> 0
```

The above does rely on all rows from table A and all rows from table B being present in the cross join result.

In general each row from table A will be represented `b_card` times - where `b_card` is the number of rows in table B. And similarly each row from table B will be represented `a_card` times.

As long as both `a_card` and `b_card` are `>=1` then all source rows are present.

The case where this falls down however is where one of these is `0` - i.e. the join is onto an empty table - then the cross join result is empty and it would be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

`LEFT JOIN` is not replaceable with `CROSS JOIN`

```
a
_
1
2

b
_
1
4
```

`a left join b is`

```
1,1
2,null
```

which is not a subset of `a cross join b`

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would be fine. The old comma syntax that came before joins came as a word is exactly that.

```
select *
from
tableA A, tableB B
where
A.Id = B.Id
```

I can't see anything you can't do with this